# Python/ Pandas : Search for a word in a DataFrame column and take it's value from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe with text column

| Text |
| --- |
| I need a new umbrella |
| I need new shoes |

I have created a dictionary like this

```
dict = {'umbrella': '1','shoes':2}
```

I want my output dataframe to look like this

| Text | Value |
| --- | --- |
| I need a new umbrealla | 1 |
| I need new shoes | 2 |

It should look for keys in a dictionary and populate the corresponding value against the row in a dataframe.

Can somebody suggest how to do it in python?

Answer (score 3):

You can try [`series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['Value'] = df['Text'].str.extract('('+'|'.join(d)+')',expand=False).map(d)
```

---

```
print(df)
                    Text Value
0  I need a new umbrella     1
1       I need new shoes     2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string and look up each word in the dictionary:

```
df['Value'] = df['Text'].str.split().apply(lambda x: [dict[i] for i in x if i in dict.keys()])

print(df)
                    Text Value
0  I need a new umbrella   [1]
1       I need new shoes   [2]
```

This returns a list of values for all matching words. If you just want 1 value, you can do `df['Value'] = df['Value'].str[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way.

```
df['Value'] = df['Text'].replace(d,regex=True).str.extract(r'(\d)')
```